# IIS 7.5 require client certificate

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, certificate

I have an asp.net website under IIS who responds at 443 port with SSL.
The website requires client certificate for authentication.
The client and server certificate are generated by third part CA, the CA is installed on Trusted Root Auth and the client and server certificate in Trusted People.
In this configuration every client with client certificate works, but if i remove client certificate from Trusted People, clients can't access and IIS responds HTTP403.

Can i configure IIS to validate client certificate only by chain trust ?

In my website i have a wcf service, i have to support interoperability and i used the basicHttpsBinding.

This is the web.config :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    <machineKey validationKey="[...]" decryptionKey="[...]" validation="SHA1" 
      decryption="AES" />
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpsGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"   
          httpsHelpPageEnabled="true" />

          <!-- I tryed this configuration to force only chain trust but with 
               no results --> 
          <!--<serviceCredentials>
            <clientCertificate>
              <authentication certificateValidationMode="ChainTrust"  
                 trustedStoreLocation="LocalMachine" revocationMode="NoCheck" />
            </clientCertificate>
          </serviceCredentials>-->

        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
         multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
      <serviceActivations>
        <add relativeAddress="V1/MyService.svc" service="MyService" />
      </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpsBinding>
        <binding name="sslHttpsBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpsBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpsBinding" contract="IMyService" 
                 bindingConfiguration="sslHttpsBinding" />
        <endpoint address="Mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"  
          />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    <!-- I used rewrite module to mask .svc service extension -->
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect requests to friendly URLs">
          <match url="^(.*?)/(.*)\.svc$" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="{R:1}/{R:2}" />
        </rule>
        <rule name="Rewrite friendly URLs to phsyical paths">
          <match url="^(.*)$" />
          <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}.svc" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I also tryed with an empty website with only the index.html page and without any web.config,
i think that the problem is how iis work.

I know that iis has a module for certificate mapping (one-to-one or one-to-many), 
but i wouldn't have client certificates installed in Trusted People on server.

The CA certificate i have is in pem format with only public key, but i don't think it could be otherwise.

Comment: Just to clarify, you're removing the client cert from the Trusted People store? Sounds like you're doing the right thing. If so, please post up as much of the web.config as you can (edit your question).